# I need some help verifying from which flutter documentation stating Center widget can be placed under MaterialApp home property

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to find a reference from flutter documentation where it states Center widget can be placed inside MaterialApp home property. Sample code below.

I can see what the below code outputs when I run it, however, I'm trying to learn/rely more in documentation than just copying/pasting code from tutorials and I am figuring out which section in the documentation where I can see that Center widget can be put in the home property.

Reading through this document
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/home.html

```
void main() {
  runApp (
    MaterialApp (
      home: Center (
    child: Text ('Hello World'),
     ),
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't make sense, the home parameter is for routing

> The widget for the default route of the app
>   (Navigator.defaultRouteName, which is /).
>
> This is the route that is displayed first when the application is
>   started normally, unless initialRoute is specified. It's also the
>   route that's displayed if the initialRoute can't be displayed.

[Center class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) is for positioning content within a view

> A widget that centers its child within itself.
>
> This widget will be as big as possible if its dimensions are
>   constrained and widthFactor and heightFactor are null.